# Function doesn't output "STRING"

Tags: php

```
<?php
function remove_char(string $s):string
    {
        settype($s, 'string');
        $pieces = str_split($s);
        unset($pieces[0]);
        $numb = count($pieces);
        unset($pieces[$numb - 1]);
        echo implode("", $pieces);
    }

    $lotsp = "lotsp";`enter code here`
    remove_char($lotsp);
?>
```

The function 'remove_char()' supposed to bring 'String' type of output. However it is outputting anything other than string.

Error: FATAL ERROR Uncaught TypeError: Return value of remove_char() must be of the type string, none returned in /home4/phptest/public_html/code.php70(5) : `enter code here`

I don't know where is the problem. Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: `string` isn't a very useful tag - what language are you using? Perl? PHP?

Comment: it is  php7 which is bringing me down

Answer (score 1):

You are declaring that `remove_char()` should return a `string` but you are not returning anything.

Remove `:string` from your function declaration:

```
function remove_char(string $s)
{
    settype($s, 'string');
    $pieces = str_split($s);
    unset($pieces[0]);
    $numb = count($pieces);
    unset($pieces[$numb - 1]);
    echo implode("", $pieces);
}
```

Now you should be able to `echo` from within the function.

See this answer about the [difference between `echo` and `return`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10903689/1140065).

Comment: You should explain the difference between a return value and output.

Comment: @Narf Added some explanation and a link to a related answer.

Comment: @Camilio I need to show something on screen, so how can 'Return' statement fix this up

Comment: `echo remove_char($lotsp);`

Comment: @Camilo I just echoed outside of the function statement..yes..it works...but I need to do this inside the function statement....

Comment: Remove `:string` from your function declaration.

Comment: Please, consider accepting the answer if it solved your problem.